# What does mongoose.save() return and is it useful?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I know that the return value is a promise, but was curious as to what `temp1` is in this case.  Currently is is returning `undefined`.

```
  let temp = DBM.saveArticle(obj).then(() => {
  });
  debug && console.log('DEBUG: /articles/add: temp ', temp);
  temp.then((temp1)=>{
    debug && console.log('DEBUG: /articles/add: temp ', temp1);
  })
```

uses:

```
// Create operations
const saveInstance = (name, schema, obj) => {
  const Model = mongoose.model(name, schema);
  return new Model(obj).save();  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The save() method is asynchronous, and according to the docs, it returns **undefined** if used with callback or a **Promise** otherwise.

So, if you want to read the created value you have to await for the promise return. In your case, wait for the value from `saveInstance` returned promise. You can do this two ways.

Using await inside an async function:

```
let created = await saveInstance(name, schema, obj);
console.log(created);
```

Or use it with `then`:

```
saveInstance(name, schema, obj).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code so we have a look?

Answer (score 1):

save() is a method on a Mongoose document. The save() method is asynchronous, so it returns a **promise** that you can await on.

When you create an instance of a Mongoose model using new, calling save() makes Mongoose insert a new document.

```
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
}));

const doc = await Person.create({ name: 'Will Riker', age: 29 });

// Setting `age` to an invalid value is ok...
doc.age = 'Lollipop';

// But trying to `save()` the document errors out
const err = await doc.save().catch(err => err);
err; // Cast to Number failed for value "Lollipop" at path "age"

// But then `save()` succeeds if you set `age` to a valid value.
doc.age = 30;
await doc.save();
```

Attaching few reference links here:-

- [Mongooose Introduction](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/save)
- [API Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save)